# What kind of analysis gives you the statement "If you DONT reach X amount by time T, then your chances go down by P percentage?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, survival

I am trying to model growth for data I have regarding downloads of applications. I would like to make a statement, if you "DONT reach X amount of downloads by time T, then your chances of reaching 15 Million users go down by 75%" Is there some sort of analysis we can do for cutoffs? Thanks!

Comment: A statement like that would imply a causal model.

Comment: You've used the tag "survival":  survival analysis (time-to-event or duration analysis) should be fruitful here.